# Chef - ERROR: Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError: could not get identity count

Tags: chef-infra, net-ssh

I am using chef-12.1 and facing issue related to "ERROR: Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError: could not get identity count". Here is what i am trying.

```
[root@home-1 installer]# knife bootstrap 9.118.36.151 -x root -P test01 -N home-1
Doing old-style registration with the validation key at /root/.chef/chef-validator.pem...
Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead

Connecting to 9.118.36.151
ERROR: Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError: could not get identity count
```

However I have passwordless setup for root user in 9.118.36.151

Not sure, what is going wrong. Can some one help on this.

Comment: By passwordless do you mean you have a public key provisioned on the remote server? In that case why are you specifying a password (-P) in the bootstrap command and not the SSH private key? (-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means it thinks there is an active ssh-agent process (i.e. `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set) but is unable to communicate with it. Your agent might have crashed or been restarted and you need to fix your environment variable(s). You can also just remove the env var so it doesn't try to use the agent at all.

Answer (score 3):

Restart the ssh-agent

```
killall ssh-agent; eval `ssh-agent`
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute this command on Chef-Workstation:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)";
```

We can also put this command in `$HOME/.bashrc`